# Cannot get a Madlibs print to work, how to fix it?

Tags: python, string, printing

Cannot get the print function to print out the Madlibs, more specifically the default play button on vs code doesn't output it, only the debug feature, I was watching a tutorial from Freecodecamp  from Youtube and the first time I tried it, no surprise it worked. Added a little more and positive that it would work, but nothing happened, output says incorrect syntax which I don't get, I believe it starts from line 1, here's the code.

```
adjective = input("Input adjective")
verb = input("Input verb")
madlib = f"I went for a -{verb}- and seen a -{adjective}- dog"

print(madlib)
```

The error I got was this

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> & C:/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/perso/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/Madlibs/game.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/perso/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/Madlibs/game.py
    ^
```

First thing I have tried is reworking the code, such as removing one adjective and one verb, to simplify and see if I could understand what went wrong, and nothing happened so I added them back, another thing I did just now was put it through debug in VSCode, it worked, but I want to know why the default play button isn't doing what I want it to do.

Comment: it looks like you're trying to run this from _inside_ a Python shell (not perhaps a PowerShell instance)

Comment: Yeah, you tried to run `C:/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/perso/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/Madlibs/game.py` as python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error looks like you are trying to run the file from inside the Python shell. Try to run the command inside Powershell. Command Prompt would also work, but you'd have to remove the `&`: `C:/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/perso/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/Madlibs/game.py`